# Can I avoid making excessive data copy by making class member references?

Tags: c++

I am solving a differential equation.
This equation can be solved by several different methods (ie finite difference, finite element etc.)
Each solver has its own set of input variables, and semantically should be a class in its own right, but all the solvers share the same or similar input, they mainly differ in a manner they calculate the solution. Let's take very reduced example:

```
class Solver
{
       std::string _type;
   public:
       std::valarray<double> get_solutions(const std::valarray<double> &x, const std::valarray<double> &y) const;
       Solver(std::string &Type) : _Type(Type) {}
}

std::vector<double> Solver::get_solutions(const std::valarray<double> &x, const std::valarray<double> &y) const
{
     if (_type == "FDM")
     {
         FDMSolver S(x,y);
         return S.get_solution();
     }
     if (_type == "FEM")
     {
         FEMSolver S(x,y);
         return S.get_solution();
     }
}
```

Now, what would be a good approach to implement classes `FDMSolver` and `FEMSolver` in terms of avoiding an excessive copy of `x` and `y` as its member variables?

Is it possible to simply place a reference member variable and is this a good programming practice?
For example, is it ok to do this:

```
class FDMSolver
{
    std::valarray<double> &x;
    std::valarray<double> &y;
   
    public:
        std::valarray<double> get_solution() const {//do something with x and y;};
        FDMSolver(cosnt std::valarray<double> &xx, const std::valarray<double> &yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {};
}
```

instead of having x and y members as arrays (in which case constructor would copy xx to x and yy to y?

I am not sure if uses of `const` in this code is valid and whether there is danger of `get_solution` method in `FDMclass` could temper with the original data in x and y arrays (I simply want a const reference to data in x and y) and is there a danger of something destroying the references before they can be used.

(Assume that FEMSolver also has get_solution method, and assume both have additional methods that do something with x and y, the example above is minimal, and there to illustrate the point on reference members)

I know a better approach would be to make a member variable solutions in the first Solver class, set get_solutions as virtual function and then derive FEMSolver and FDMSolver and implement different ways get_solutions method may behave and they would then be void functions that populate the solutions array.

Another option would be to pack x and y into a structure and provide a shared pointer to it in FDMSolver and FEMSolver, but in my code, I am passing 4 arrays, and I dislike making pointers just to wrap some data and am wondering is there an established idiom on how to handle cases like this: you have a problem where it makes sense to have reference data members?

I saw this [post](https://lesleylai.info/en/const-and-reference-member-variables/), but I don't fully understand it and am wondering if std::reference_wrapper could help?

Comment: Perhaps you have oversimplified, but I don't see the point to having classes here at all. A `fdm_get_solution(cosnt std::valarray<double> &x, const std::valarray<double> &y)` free function seems simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Yes I oversimplified.
FDM has 5 additional methods that do something. Similarly FEM has several methods (for this problem) that does something different than FDM. They only share x and y data and have method get_solution(...).

To be exact, I am solving eigenvalue problem with FDM approach that needs to generate some system matrix of 3*x.size(), and I am also implementing a transfer matrix approach which analyitically links solutions across several methods that do someting x.size() times. I am also contemplating FEM solver, that is a bit different than FDM approach.

Comment: Making members references may avoid a few copies, but you then have a huge responsability ensuring that whatever you reference is still alive when you try to use it - that's not always easy.

Comment: Are instances of these classes going into containers or being stored long-term?

Comment: Solvers won't go into any container, solutions will. Once get_solution method is called, the result will be kept, Solver class gets destroyed right after the call to get_solutions.

Comment: In that case I'd formally `delete` the assignment operator and copy constructor to prevent misuse and use plain-vanilla references. That just leaves open the issue of whether to `const` or not. I like to start with `const` and only move from that position if forced.

Comment: OT: [Each identifier that begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#name-3.1)

Comment: Regardless of anything else, references as class members are bad, because they make your class non-assignable. Prefer pointers. `std::reference_wrapper` doesn't have any benefit over a pointer.